# Change element position on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code in jQuery Mobile that when I click the image it becames bigger.

I need the image to move the left and up.

I try this:

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
        <p><img  id="zPIC" height="150" width="150" onclick="ZX();"/></p>
</div>


function ZX() {
    var img = $("#zPIC");
    if (img.width() < 200) {
       img.animate({ width: "200px", height: "200px", left: "20px", top: "20px" }, 1000);
    }
    else {
       img.animate({ width: img.attr("width"), height: img.attr("height") }, 1000);
    }
}
```

**But the picture only grows and does not move sideways**

Comment: What do you mean by moving sideways? HTML and CSS lays out item on a left-to-right, top-to-bottom manner. So if you increase the image size, the image will of course grow towards the right and bottom. Also, try to avoid using inline JS, and use event handlers instead.

Comment: Try to modify the margin or padding. Left and rigth aplly only when the element is relatively or absolutly positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set position attribute, e.g. to relative or absolute. E.g.:

```
<div id="zPIC" style="position:relative; width:150px; min-height:150px; background:green"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#zPIC").click(function(){
    if ($("#zPIC").width() < 200) {
      // store the original sizes
      $(this).data('width', $(this).css('width'));
      $(this).data('height', $(this).css('height'));
      $("#zPIC").animate({ width: "200px", height: "200px", left: "20px", top: "20px"      }, 1000);
    }
    else {
      $("#zPIC").animate({ width: $(this).data('width'), height: $(this).data('height'), }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help !, its work - but only grows , and if i press again -> it dosnt Returns to its original size